# How to use a Vowpal Wabbit model outside of python

Tags: python, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I have a question about how to use values generated by VW outside of python. For example, I have the following "readable output" from VW:

```
Feature1:221152:-0.0342143
Feature2:115611:-0.003415
Feature3:230533:-0.0162561
Feature4:222340:-0.0244261
Constant:116060:-0.74116
Feature5:240651:0.0662623
Feature6:201380:0.568669
Feature7:168515:0.00426367
Feature8:107643:-0.00488802
Feature9:25461:0.0186098
Feature10:172852:-0.00895446
```

If I have the following data point:

```
1 1 'datapoint1 | Feature10:0 Feature5:0 Feature3:0 Feature7:22 Feature4:7 Feature6:0.603153898117 Feature2:0 Feature1:0 Feature8:0 Feature9:0
```

That gives me the following results when I test through VW:

```
0.383351 datapoint1
```

But when I try to recreate that final value manually, I get a much different result:

```
-0.74116+(0.00426367*22)+(-0.0244261*7)+(0.568669*0.603153898117) = -0.475347035911703727
Constant    Feature7        Feature4          Feature6
```

I am using a logistic loss function. Does anyone have any idea how we are supposed to use the values that VW generates outside of the VW framework? I am at a loss of how these generated values are supposed to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a [logistic transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Mathematical_properties) to your result (because you used logistic regression)

```
f(y) = 1/(1+e(-y)) = 1/(1+exp(-(-0.475347))) = 0.38335
```

you get the same result as you see in VW.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I can't believe I didn't put the pieces together before!